# Fetch and store data from multiple url for the sections data of SectionList

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch

I would like to use the `SectionList` in react native.

```
export default class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: [
                {
                    title: 'New List', data: []
                },
                {
                    title: 'Old list', data: []
                },
            ]
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <SectionList
                style={styles.SectionContainer}
                sections={this.state.dataSource}
                renderSectionHeader={this._renderSectionHeader}
                renderItem={this._renderItem}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Each section's data can be fetched by separate url, and they basically have the same json data:

```
getNewList() {
    const url = website + '/api/new-list/';
    return fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
},

getOldList() {
    const url = website + '/api/old-list/';
    return fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
}
```

How can fetch and store both the response data for the `dataSource` of `SectionList`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to fire off multiple promises and wait for all to complete. [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#concurrency) has an awesome `.all` helper utility that lets you pass in an array of promises and then waits for all of them to finish before running resolving:

```
function getUserAccount() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345');
}

function getUserPermissions() {
  return axios.get('/user/12345/permissions');
}

axios.all([getUserAccount(), getUserPermissions()])
  .then(axios.spread(function (acct, perms) {
    // Both requests are now complete
  }));
```

You can also do something close to this using native Promises:

```
getLists(){
    this.getListData().then( responses => {
         this.setState({
            dataSource: [
                {
                    title: 'New List', data: responses[0]
                },
                {
                    title: 'Old list', data: responses[1]
                },
             ]
         )};
    });
}
getListData(){
    return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
       let completes = 0;
       let responses = [];
       let url = website + '/api/new-list/';
       fetch(url)
          .then((res) => {
              responses.push(res.json());
              completes++;
              if(completes === 2){
                  resolve(responses);
              }
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err));

       url = website + '/api/old-list/';
       fetch(url)
          .then((res) => {
              responses.push(res.json());
              completes++;
              if(completes === 2){
                  resolve(responses);
              }
          })
          .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, using axios made it much better. Thank you.